# Selecting all rows where 1 attribute is distinct exactly two times. (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, workbench

Say we have a table 'colours'

```
id    colour
1     'Blue'
2     'Red'
2     'Red'
3     'Blue'
3     'Red'
4     'Blue'
4     'Red'
4     'Blue'
4     'Yellow'
5     'Blue'
5     'Yellow'
```

The query should return ids 3 and 5, as they have exactly two different colours. The colours cant be the same and the amount of distinct colors needs to be exactly 2.

I tried this:

```
SELECT id FROM colours WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT colour) = 2;
```

but it gave an error sadly.

Comment: Aggregate expressions cannot be referenced in the WHERE clause.  Conditions in the WHERE clause are evaluated when rows are *retrieved*. Aggregate expressions (SUM, COUNT, etc.) cannot be evaluated until *after* the rows are retrieved. Conditions on aggregates are allowed in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You are close:

```
SELECT id
FROM colours
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colour) = 2;
```